# Adding class to elements in a loop processing AJAX response

Tags: javascript, ajax

AJAX request returns XML containing such nodes:

```
<root>
  <directory><li onclick=myFunc()>stuff</li></directory>
  ...
</root>
```

Then code processes it like this:

```
var folderContent = '';
var data = xhttp.responseXML;
var folders = data.getElementsByTagName("directory");
for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
                    folderContent += folders[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
document.getElementById('folders').innerHTML = folderContent;
```

I want to add to every list item one class (identical to every element). How should I do that using JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
var li;

for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
     li = document.createElement('li');
     li.innerHTML = folders[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     li.setAttribute('onclick', 'Toggle(this, true)');
     li.setAttribute('class', 'first-level');
     ul.appendChild(li);
     }
document.getElementById('folders').innerHTML = ul.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAttribute to set add(or change) an attribute. Also I notice you are calling nodeValue on an element node which is always undefined.
 If your aim is to append the li node to folderContent then you will have to serialize it to string before appending to folderContent.

```
    var folderContent = '';
    var data = xhttp.responseXML;
    var folders = data.getElementsByTagName("directory");
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var node;
    for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        node=folders[i].childNodes[0];
        node.setAttribute('class', 'your-class')//sets class attribute to li node
        folderContent += serializer.serializeToString(node);//serialize li node before and appends it to  folderContent
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I couldn't invoke *setAttribute* on the node. Also XMLSerializer is a C# class and I needed to work with JS only. Though your suggestion led me to the right approach, thanks.

Comment: @ElijahDollin I'm glad u are able to fix your issue but do note that XMLSerializer in this context is a JS object and hs nothing to do with c#